# Merge multiple video with ffmpeg single command line in specific time without cut it one by one and merge it

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 15 video files which I want to merge with ffmpeg. I want to save time by merge all of the video files in a single command line, not cut it one by one and merge it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat).

First, create a text file with the filenames.

```
file '1.mp4'
file '2.mp4'
file '3.mp4'
...
file '13.mp4'
file '14.mp4'
file '15.mp4'
```

Then, run the concat command.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i textfile -c copy -fflags +genpts merged.mp4
```

For this to work, all videos should have same properties such as codec, resolution, framerate, sample rate, etc.

If they are not, you can encode the concat.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i textfile -fflags +genpts merged.mp4
```

Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: Concatenate](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Comment: Please explain how to "encode the concat". The command line you have provided for this does not work for me. Could you perhaps provide an example?

Comment: @Arete Post a new Q with log of your ffmpeg command execution as well as properties of the input files  + the list as well.

Comment: Second command is working well but audio is missing!

Answer (score 1):

Gyan's suggestion did not work for me. The output video from the suggested commands had the same duration as the first input, and so video 2 and 3 content was missing, and my media player crashed trying to play the output.

I did however find my answer in the reference he provided: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#filter

```
ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 -i v2.mp4 -i v3.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" v_out.mp4
```

This command worked for videos all having both video and audio streams. For one video not having audio, I modify the command slightly like so:

```
ffmpeg -i v1_NoAudio.mp4 -i v2.mp4 -i v3.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0][1:v:0][2:v:0]concat=n=3:v=1[outv]" -map "[outv]" v_out_NoAudio.mp4
```

Effectively, I just removed any portions of the command about audio. This discards the audio from the second and third videos, as a rule of using this filter is that the channels remain the same in all videos.

Comment: This worked for me, because input files differed in metadata (although I could not tell what was wrong, since they had apparently the same resolution, codec, etc...).